# Present Next ViewController to Dismiss current ViewController Using Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

My Scenario, I have three `ViewControllers`, those `ViewControllers` First, Second, Third. Here, First `ViewController` `UIButton` click to present model second `ViewController` and then Second `ViewController` `UIButton` click to present model Third `ViewController`. I need to Implement the Second `ViewController` button click to dismiss current `ViewController` after presenting Third `ViewController` because once I close Third `ViewController` I need to show First `ViewController`. How to Achieve this?

NOTE: I am having NavigationController for Third `ViewController` also I am using `Storyboard`.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func ClickThirdVC(_ sender: Any) {
    if let VC_Third = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdviewcontroller") as? ThirdvViewController {
        weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController
        VC_B.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC_B)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            pvc?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to dismiss self after presenting the third `UIViewController`, in the completion handler of the present function .

```
secondVC?.present(navController, animated: true) {
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) //dismiss self after presenting the third. 
        }
```

Comment: Above code where I need to place? within second or this viewcontroller? @Mohammad S

Comment: @JamKu in the second VC where you present the third VC

Comment: Based on your solution I am getting crash

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <UINavigationController: 0x13001ca00>.' @Mohammad S

Comment: are you calling it twice ? or did u replaced the code ?

Comment: if let VC_Third = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “thirdviewcontroller”) as? ThirdViewController {
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC_Third)
            VC_Third.present(navController, animated: true) {
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) //dismiss self after presenting the third.
            }
        } @Mohammad S

Comment: you're using it wrong you need to call `self.present` not `VC_Third.present`

Comment: Its not working. Still some problem. Third viewcontroller Navigation bar showing without color and also third viewcontroller dismiss immidiatly after presenting. @Mohmmad S